# Adding subview to superview shared by a container view resizes container view

Tags: ios, uiview

I have a view controller whose view has a container view as a subview. I set the initial frame of the container view in IB and later change it according to if an iAd loaded in a banner. If I add another subview to the view controller's view the container view's frame gets resized back to the frame set in IB.

I have no idea why this is happening and appreciate any help. I created a test app to eliminate all of the other variables so I know this is the situation.

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: Yes, I am using auto layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using auto layout, you can't set the frames of views you load from a xib or storyboard.  Auto layout sets the frames, and it ignores changes you make to the frames.  You need to update the constraints on those views if you need to move or resize them directly.

You can create an outlet pointing to an `NSLayoutConstraint` in your view controller, and connect the outlet to the appropriate constraint in your xib or storyboard.  Then you can change the constraint's `constant` property to change the view's position or height.

Comment: Thank you, I will see if I can figure that out! (Auto layout is new to me.)